# Angular 2: Observable from multiple Events or Eventhandler

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

I grouped multiple Inputs and their events in the component template like this:

```
<tr (input)="onSearchObjectChange($event)">
    <th><input [(ngModel)]="searchObject.prop1"></th>
    <th><input [(ngModel)]="searchObject.prop2"></th>
    ...
</tr>
```

---

Now I want to create an Observable out of the `onSearchObjectChange()`, which should get the result of an Promise. How would I do this or is there a better way to use an Observable? Can I use the `distinctUntilChanged()` function for Objects too?

I tried to solve it with a template variable:

```
<tr #search >
<th><input [(ngModel)]="searchObject.prop1"></th>
<th><input [(ngModel)]="searchObject.prop2"></th>
...
</tr>
```

And with the help of ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild('search') search;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    Observable.fromEvent(this.search, 'input')
        .subscribe(() => console.log("help"));
}
```

But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Component({
    selector: 'search',
    templateUrl: './search.html',
    styleUrls: ['./search.css'],
    providers: []
})
export class SearchComponent implements AfterViewInit {
@ViewChild('search') search: ElementRef;

constructor() {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    Observable.fromEvent(this.search.nativeElement, 'input')
        .subscribe(() => alert("It works!"))
}
}
```